# Cannot access multiple columns from multiple databases outside for loops

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

I was given a project to take a lot of php5 code and update it to php7 (mainly changing all mysql_ functions to mysqli_). With this file in particular,I need to display different columns of information from 3 different databases. If this were just one query, then I could place my html within a loop, but I am getting info across several DBs.

While checking my apache error.log, I keep getting "Undefined variable" for every variable that is within the html.

How can I properly get the results of these 3 queries to be used later on the page?

**Note:** My config file is correct since all the other pages work that access these databases.

```
$Master_Status_Query = "show master status";
$NS10_Status_Query = "show slave status";
$NS11_Status_Query = "show slave status";

$master_result = $master_conn->query($master_conn, $Master_Status_Query);
$ns10_result = $ns10_conn->query($ns10_conn, $NS10_Status_Query);
$ns11_result = $ns11_conn->query($ns11_conn, $NS11_Status_Query);


if($master_result === FALSE) {
    print '<p class="input--error">Something broke: ' . mysqli_error($master_conn);
} else {
    foreach($master_result as $master_row) {
        $Master_Log_Name = $master_row['File'];
                $Master_Log_Position = $master_row['Position'];
    }
}
if($ns10_result === FALSE) {
    print '<p class="input--error">Something broke: '. mysqli_error($ns10_conn);
} else {
    foreach($ns10_result as $ns10_row) {
        $NS10_Log_Name = $ns10_row['Master_Log_File'];
        $NS10_Log_Position = $ns10_row['Read_Master_Log_Position'];
        $NS10_Seconds_Behind_Master = $ns10_row['Seconds_Behind_Master'];
    }
}
if($ns11_result === FALSE) {
    print '<p class="input--error">Something broke: '.mysqli_error($ns11_conn);
} else {
    foreach($ns11_result as $ns11_row) {
        $NS11_Log_Name = $ns11_row['Master_Log_File'];
        $NS11_Log_Position = $ns11_row['Read_Master_Log_Position'];
        $NS11_Seconds_Behind_Master = $ns11_row['Seconds_Behind_Master'];
    }
}

mysqli_close($master_conn);
mysqli_close($ns10_conn);
mysqli_close($ns11_conn);


echo "<table id=\"replication_table\">";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\" align=\"center\">Server Replication Status</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\">&nbsp;</td></tr>";
echo "<tr bgcolor=\"darkblue\"><td width=\"30%\"align=\"left\"><font color=\"white\">Server</font></td><td width=\"30%\"align=\"left\"><font color=\"white\">Log File</font></td><td colspan=\"3\" width=\"30%\"align=\"left\"><font color=\"white\">Log Position</font></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td align=\"left\">Master</td><td align=\"left\">$Master_Log_Name</td><td align=\"left\">$Master_Log_Position</td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp;                     </td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp; </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td align=\"left\">NS10  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS10_Log_Name  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS10_Log_Position  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS10_Seconds_Behind_Master</td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp; </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td align=\"left\">NS11  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS11_Log_Name  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS11_Log_Position  </td><td align=\"left\">$NS11_Seconds_Behind_Master</td><td align=\"left\">&nbsp; </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td align=\"left\"><button class='btn btn-default' type=\"button\" onClick=\"myRef = location.replace('db-integrity-check.php','mywin');\">Back To Menu</button></td></tr></br>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing the code to this:

```
$Master_Status_Query = "show master status";
$NS10_Status_Query = "show slave status";
$NS11_Status_Query = "show slave status";

$master_result = mysqli_query($master_conn, "show master status");
$ns10_result = mysqli_query($ns10_conn, "show slave status");
$ns11_result = mysqli_query($ns11_conn, "show slave status");

$master_row = $master_result->fetch_array();
$ns10_row = $ns10_result->fetch_array();
$ns11_row = $ns11_result->fetch_array();

$Master_Log_Name = $master_row['File'];
$Master_Log_Position = $master_row['Position'];

$NS10_Log_Name = $ns10_row['Master_Log_File'];
$NS10_Log_Position = $ns10_row['Read_Master_Log_Pos'];
$NS10_Seconds_Behind_Master = $ns10_row['Seconds_Behind_Master'];

$NS11_Log_Name = $ns11_row['Master_Log_File'];
$NS11_Log_Position = $ns11_row['Read_Master_Log_Pos'];
$NS11_Seconds_Behind_Master = $ns11_row['Seconds_Behind_Master'];



mysqli_close($master_conn);
mysqli_close($ns10_conn);
mysqli_close($ns11_conn);
```

I was getting an Access Denied error. After granting SUPER privileges to the database, the records displayed correctly.